# Making JQuery appear in front of images

Tags: jquery, image, photoshop, hidden, slice

So, I created a page with Photoshop slices, and I noticed JQuery code does not appear. I'm suspecting it's hidden underneath the images, so I tried z-index to no avail.

Is there a way to make JQuery items appear in front of images? They do appear if I delete away slices of the image.

Edit: Sorry about that: Let me provide images and sample of the code when I'm able to.

I used the JQuery Plugin from this website: http://gristmill.github.com/jquery-popbox/

Snippets of the code, basically I'm trying to make a mock pop up contact box when Contact is clicked. However it came up like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUAhx.png

```
#tweetspage-07 {
    position:absolute;
    left:564px;
    top:1px;
    width:108px;
    height:59px;
    z-index:-1;

}

 <!--Contacts-->
    <div id="tweetspage-07">


<div class='popbox'>
    <a class='open' href='#'><img src="images/tweetspage_07.png" width="108" height="59" alt=""></a>


          <div class='collapse'>
            <div class='box'>
              <div class='arrow'></div>
              <div class='arrow-border'></div>

              Content in PopBox goes here :)
              <a href="#" class="close">close</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You'll need to show some code.

Comment: Please come with proper description and sample code .. thanks

Comment: `JQuery code` should never appear. However, if you properly describe what you are trying to achieve, we could maybe help.

Comment: I think you have muddled words and that your HTML element is not appearing in-front of your images. Firstly make sure it has a positive `z-index` that is higher than the images and that it has a `position` property other than `static`.

Answer (score 0):

Give z-index a positive value higher than the contend currently appearing above. make the JQuery items display:-Block; position:absolute;